# Can you install APKs programmatically using Beeware?

Tags: python, android, beeware

I'm making a GUI app for a package manager I'm working on, but I don't if you can install APKs programmatically using Beeware. I'm using Beeware because it's the only library I'm comfortable using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about programmatic APK installation specifically, but if you can find the Java API for doing that, then you can call it from your BeeWare app using the Chaquopy API described [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html).